# Alternative for JavaScript Math Range?

Tags: javascript

I saw this gist to change RGB color to RGBA, but JS Math does not have a range method. Is there any way to convert the range method here?

```
function rgba(hex, opacity) {
    var colours = hex.regex(/#?([0-9A-F]{2})([0-9A-F]{2})([0-9A-F]{2})/i).map(function(val) {
        return Math.range(0, parseInt(val, 16), 255);
    }).join(",");
    if (opacity === undefined) {
        return "rgb(" + colours + ")";
    }
    return "rgba(" + colours + "," + opacity + ")";
}
```

Found this here: https://gist.github.com/Rycochet/8597336

Comment: Hi, http://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/range.html  ??

Comment: thanks @AlexyHody. I am trying to stay away from any 3rd party. Just want to be able to do this with regular JS.

Comment: If you looked at Rycochet's other gists, you'd find [the source](https://gist.github.com/Rycochet/8597399) with ease.

Comment: @AlexyHody thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Note that `regex` is also not a method of the String type.

Comment: @ScottSauyet indeed, that source can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Rycochet/8597361)

Comment: @NickA: Sorry, missed some of the discussion.  This is not how I would choose to solve the problem, but it certainly works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fulfill the color conversion without `range`

```
function rgba(hex, opacity) {
    var colours = hexToRgb(hex);
    if (opacity === undefined) {
        return "rgb(" + colours + ")";
    }
    return "rgba(" + colours + "," + opacity + ")";
}

function hexToRgb(hex) {
    var bigint = parseInt(hex, 16);
    var r = (bigint >> 16) & 255;
    var g = (bigint >> 8) & 255;
    var b = bigint & 255;

    return r + "," + g + "," + b;
}
```

The function `hexToRgb(hex)` was from  [RGB to Hex and Hex to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb)

Comment: thank you for the response. In regards to the way that `Math.range` is being used in this case, how would I convert that to not be using `range`

Comment: I updated it with a code to  fulfill the color conversion without `range`

Answer (score 2):

It appears to me that `range` method just clamps the value.  You can do that by combining `max` and `min` methods.

```
Math.range = function(min, val, max) {
  return Math.max(min, Math.min(val, max));
};
```

Comment: Or `var clamp = (min, val, max) => val < min ? min : val > max ? max : val`.  `range` is an odd name for this function.  I've usually seen `range(3, 6) //=> [3, 4, 5, 6]` or some variant of it..